# I need help with the powers of an integer, modulo m

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am currently reading a chapter in math textbook  about the powers of an integer, modulo m. I am having troubles with the following claims

Suppose that $a^r \equiv a^s(mod\text{ } m)$, where $r>s$. Then $a^s(a^{r-s}-1)\equiv 0(mod\text{ } m)$, and since $(a^s,m)=(a,m)=1$, we must have $a^{r-s} \equiv 1(mod\text{ } m)$. But then $a^{r-s+1} \equiv a$, $a^{r-s+2} \equiv a^2$. (I am clear with the latter).

(I am not clear with the following:) Moreover ,1, which is the first element of the sequence, is also the first number to repeat. For suppose the opposite: that the second occurrence of 1 is at the power $a^n$, and that for some $r$ and $s$ with $0<s<r<n$, we have $a^r \equiv a^s(mod\text{ } m)$. Then, just as before, we can deduce that $a^{r-s} \equiv 1(mod\text{ } m)$, which contradicts the definition of n, since $0<r-s<n$.

Can anybody explain me what's going on in the latter claim?. What is n?. Are they trying to show how this is true by assuming that there is another number that is not one that shows up first when the sequence repeats?. What do they mean with the second of occurrence of 1 is at the power of $a^n$?

Answer (score 1):

The latter claim shows that $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^n \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ m)$.

By multiplying $a$ starting from $1$ we get a sequence $1,\ a,\ a^2,\cdots$. Under mod $m$ this sequence is finite, which means that we will have the first $a^r\equiv a^s\ (\text{mod}\ m)\ (r>s)$ by at most $m$ multiplications, hence $a^{r-s}\equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ m)$. What's more, the sequence forms a [cyclic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) $\{1,a,a^2,\cdots,a^{n-1}\}$ whose [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) is $n=r-s$.